# How to work with the amocrm.v2 library in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write code in python3 and use the amocrm.v2 library. I'm trying to get all the fields out of Leads, but some objects have strange values. Here is an example:

```
today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
tasks = Lead.objects.all()

current = datetime.today().date()

n = 0

for task in tasks:
    if str(task.created_at.date()) == '2023-04-21':

        n += 1

        print(n, task, task.name)



OUTPUT:
Lead(account_id = 30852334, closed_at = None, closest_task_at = 2023-04-21 05:36:16, contacts = <amocrm.v2.fields._ListData object at 0x10c302f10>, created_at = 2023-04-21 05:31:15, group_id = 0, id = 8659237, is_deleted = False, loss_reason = [], loss_reason_id = None, name = Заявка от (Алексей — Виза в Болгарию Австрию), None = <class 'amocrm.v2.entity.note.NotesField.on_get_instance.<locals>.Note'>, price = 0, score = None, updated_at = 2023-04-21 05:31:17)
```

Please help me, I need to output absolutely all values in normal form

I tried to create a class, but nothing good came of it, I can't figure out how to output all the values in normal form, if someone has ideas how to implement it, I will be very happy